# error while Inserting Column into Table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using the PUBS database of microsoft in c# programming language
I am using Micosoft SQL server Management Studio too.

In this there is a table.  When I am trying to insert a record into any table and save this table the error message will give like this

> Save Changes is not Permitted this changes to be required the following table to be dropped and re-create you have either made changes to the table that's cant be created and enabled the option prevent saving changes that required to be recreated **

So what is the problem?

Comment: Is this happening in Management studio or in your code?

Comment: @MikeTwo It's a very specific SSMS error.

Answer (score 3):

It's a configurable option to prevent users from running commands that they **think** will be simple `ALTER` statements, but actually require the whole table and its data to be `DROP` and `CREATE` again:

```
Tools > Options

Designers > Table and Database Designers

Uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is settings that is made under the option of Database designer section to prevent DDL operation. 
Disable the `option prevent saving changes that required to be recreated` in your SQL Server option.

> You will find this under tools menu > Option > Designer > Uncheck the
>   checkbox *prevent saving changes that require table re-creation*.
>
> In Visual Studio tools menu > Option > Database Tools > Table and
>   Database Designer > Uncheck the check box *prevent saving changes that
>   require table re-creation*.

Hope this help